# SQL query to get column name and datatype in which the tables are located in two server's databases

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2005

I have two tables `tableA` in `databaseA` on `ServerA` and `tableB` in `databaseB` on `ServerB`.

I just want to get the column names and datatypes that are same in two tables `A & B`. I need a SQL query using `sysobjects` and `syscolumns` (it should not use information schema). I am so confused to write the query for it. Now I am using information schema on this query.

I am using following query to get column name and datatype. Please give another query for the same purpose using  `sysobjects` and `syscolumns` (it should not use information schema)
I am using SQL Server 2005.

```
SELECT 
    t1.column_name, t2.column_name, t1.data_type, t2.data_type 
FROM 
    (select * from serverA.databaseA.information_schema.COLUMNS 
     WHERE table_name ='tableA') as t1 
full outer join
    (select * from severB.databaseB.information_schema.COLUMNS 
     WHERE table_name ='tableA') as t2 ON t1.column_name=t2.column_name;
```

Comment: Would you like to accomplish this in C#?

Comment: I assume this is SQL Server as opposed to Oracle, DB2 etc, if so please add a tag that indicates this.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace :

```
select * from serverA.databaseA.information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name ='tableA'
```

By :

```
select serverA.syscolumns.name AS column_name, serverA.syscolumns.length AS column_length, serverA.systypes.name AS data_type
  from serverA.syscolumns, serverA.systypes, serverA.sysobjects 
  where sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id 
  and 'TableA' = sysobjects.name 
  and syscolumns.type = systypes.type
```